# Font-family in canvas

Tags: javascript, css

```
fillCenteredText("Space Invaders", CANVAS_WIDTH/2, CANVAS_HEIGHT/2.75, '#FFFFFF' , 36);
  fillBlinkingText("Press enter to play!", CANVAS_WIDTH/2, CANVAS_HEIGHT/2, 500, '#FFFFFF', 36);
```

So I do this, but im trying to figure out how to make a font-family for the canvas

Comment: Hi! You'll need to provide a lot more context before we can help you out. Please try to post enough code for a working example.